# Grafana | Auth Proxy - Security

Tags: grafana

I am trying to implement Grafana Auth Proxy as documented at

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/auth-proxy/
- https://community.grafana.com/t/django-auth-valid-session-on-grafana-behind-nginx/2793/6

Based on how it works, it seems `X-WEBAUTH-USER` is set in plain text. So any one who can spoof it, can get logged in.

Grafana does have a IP Whitelist, BUT I dont think its practice to maintain IP Addresses of Docker Containers (Django and Grafana are running in separate docker containers).

**Questions**:

1. Is there a better implementation to achieve some thing more secured?
2. Can whitelist have a easier value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is design. AuthProxy offloads the authentication to your own legacy "auth" server. Of course you will need to secure connection between auth server and Grafana, so no one will be able to spoof it. For example you may create dedicated docker network (mutual TLS connection, VPN, ...), where users don't have access. The best approach depends on used infrastructure. If you are not able to secure this communication properly, then AuthProxy  is not the best auth method for you.

IMHO the best authentication (and single sign on) protocol supported also by Grafana is Open ID Connect (or SAML for Grafana Enteprise). But you will need Identity Provider, which will support these standards.

Comment: I want to connect to [AD FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services) and [SAML Auth](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/saml/) is in Enterprise only. So was trying alternatives

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Why you don use Keycloak (or another IdP with AD support), which will be connected to Active Directory, so you will have pretty solid Identity Provider with SAML/OIDC support. Then you will just connect Keycloak-Grafana via OIDC https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/